# How to use ARM intrinsics in iOS?

Tags: ios, arm, neon, intrinsics

I need to compute MSB (most significant bit) on millions of 32-bit integers on iPad very fast. I have my own (ugly) implementation of MSB written on plain C, which is slow. ARM processors have **CLZ** (count leading zeroes) hardware command, which can be very useful for that. According to [ARM reference](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CJAJBHHA.html) there is an intrinsic C function __CLZ. How can I add support of ARM intrinsic functions to my Xcode project?

P.S. I've managed to find the way of accessing hardware CLZ from NEON (by including arm_neon.h), but that's not what I need, because it's only works with vector, but I need scalar MSB.

Comment: Can you not just use inline asm code?

Comment: I don't know how to write inline asm, yet ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found ARM intrinsic functions names on page 44 of [ARM C language extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053a/IHI0053A_acle.pdf). Some of them works in Xcode. This prints 31, as expected:

```
NSLog(@"%u", __builtin_clz(1));
```

Notes:

- I haven't found any references of this in Apple docs. Most likely Xcode inherited those functions from LLVM or CLANG.
- You don't need to include any special headers or frameworks to use those functions. Xcode IDE autocomplete doesn't know about them.
- Only a few functions from extensions list are implemented. According to pages 12-13 of the same document it should be two header files: arm_acle.h for non-NEON intrinsics and arm_neon.h for NEON intrinsics. Xcode have only the second file, but some of the functions from the first file declared somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious, but if if you use ARM-specific instructions, you will not be able to run your app in the iOS simulator. The simulator uses the native x86-64 hardware of your Mac.

You could create a wrapper function that uses a compiler directive to use the ARM command or fall back to the "ugly" code if you don't have support.

Comment: I don't use simulator. Can you explain how can I add CLZ to code? I've tried to add ``clz, CLZ, __clz, __builtin_clz__``, etc... functions, but they simply doesn't declared anywhere. I've also tried ``grep -R "clz" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain`` but found only links to NEON and x86